# Trouble designing grunt workflow, with rev and usemin, for webdev

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-usemin

I'm going to start using grunt-rev & grunt-usemin with grunt-watch for my web development needs (a RESTful Web App specifically).

I have a local development machine which will run grunt-watch to attach revision identifiers on my JS files. I `git commit` and `git push` my tree to a git repo, and then ask the production server to `git pull` the changes from the git repo to show them to the web visitors.

**The problem** is that I don't want my git repo to store different filenames (due to `grunt-rev`) on each commit. That would be bad, because then I wouldn't be able to do `git diff` between commits without having my screen get flooded with the contents of files that appear and disappear, and also it could (sometimes) take up a lot more storage than if it only stored the small diffs of the files.

The only solution I see is to add the `build` directory containing the versioned filenames in my `.gitignore`, so as to not store those files (with the constantly changing filenames) in git. But wouldn't that mean that I would have to run `grunt-watch` on my production server as well, in order to produce the `build` directory with the versioned filenames there as well? But that gets complicated: a new process has to run on the remote server, maybe with its small chances of error in processing the files. Not the solution I was hoping for.

Do you people have another solution? What would you suggest I did?

Answer (score 1):

What I do to solve this, is to remove previous "build" files before committing and deploying a new file. There is no need to keep older files that have been generated, because you can always rebuild them with the source files (which are in git).

Comment: If you remove `/build` before committing, then the git repository does not contain `/build`, so where does the production server download `/build` from?

Comment: I keep /build in my git repo and use something like this to clean it of old versions before commit: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean

Comment: You mean the git repo has an empty `/build` directory? Or does it have a `/build` that contains only new and relevant files, as opposed to containing old garbage that hasn't been cleaned?

Comment: Yes it only contains the last build, so you can use that on your production server as well.

Comment: So you get different filenames (containing revision ids) in every commit, in your git repo?

Comment: For external CSS/JS files yes, also prevents caching